# Google Apps Script add 1 to the value of a cell in a spreadsheet on button click

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a sign up app where it counts the number of yes, maybe and no responses. Can someone show me how to add 1 to the value of a cell within a spreadsheet from an app? Below is the function that I am using for the Yes button on my app, I have added the click handler to the app.

```
function yesButton(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet ID').getSheets()[0];
  var yesCount = ss.getRange("A2");
  var yesAdd = yesCount.getValues();
  var yesTotal = (yesAdd.value) + 1;
  yesTotal.setValue(yesAdd);

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `getValues()`, you obtain a 2D array. Which is referenced like this. `yesAdd[row#][col#]`. Instead, you should use the function `getValue()` which returns just a single value (not in an array).

Just change the one line to

```
var yesAdd = yesCount.getValue();
```

Then write back to the cell that you read it from.

```
yesCount.setValue(yesAdd+1);
```

`yesCount` still refers to the cell that you'd like to edit, so we set the value on that cell.

Comment: good explanation. Everything below 'var ss=...' could be ss.getRange("A2").setValue(ss.getRange("A2").getValue()+1);

Answer (score 0):

Just used this and it worked perfectly, wanted a simple plus minus script to use with some invisible buttons and it works.

I just split mine into plus and minus for current sheet..

> ```
> function plus() {
>
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>
> var yesCount = ss.getRange("B7");
>
> var yesAdd = yesCount.getValue();
>
> yesCount.setValue(yesAdd+1);
>
> }
> ```
>
> .
>
> ```
> function minus() {
>
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>
> var yesCount = ss.getRange("B7");
>
> var yesAdd = yesCount.getValue();
>
> yesCount.setValue(yesAdd-1);
>
> }
> ```