# Issue Looping through Google Spreadsheet and Retrieving Cell Values

Tags: google-apps-script

My apologies in advance for any stupid questions... I'm a completely new to JS and scripting in Google Docs.

I'm trying to write a bit of code to delete all the rows in a google spreadsheet that has the word "Received" or "Canceled" in the first column of the row.

Here is my current code:

```
function DeleteClosedRows() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var end = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
    for( var i = 3; i < end + 1; ++i ) {
        var value =  ss.getActiveRange().getCell(i, 1).getValue();
        if (value === "Received" && value === "Canceled") {
            sheet.deleteRows(i); 
        };
    };  
};
```

When I try to run this I get the error "Cell reference out of range"

When I look at the Execution Transcript it says the last action taken was:
Range.getCell([3, 1])

.. I'm sure there are 100 things wrong with my code, but for now I'd love to understand the first issue that's stoping it from getting past that part.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not related to your question, but you're gonna want to change `&&` to `||`. This changes AND to OR. You want to check if the value is "Received" OR if the value is "Cancelled".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your code is failing is because `.getActiveRange()` returns the range of cells that are currently selected by the user. This is not what you want. Instead, you will want to get a range from the sheet that consists of a single cell. Something like this:

```
var value =  ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
```

`.getRange` with two arguments functions exactly like you expect `.getCell`.

**Note:** When you call `.getRange`, you can get a whole range of cells (just like you can select multiple cells in the spreadsheet. Then when you call `.getValue`, you get the value of the *first* cell in that range.

**Note for performance:** You can retrieve the values of a whole range of cells at once by calling `.getValues`. This returns a 2D array containing all of the values at once. This is much faster than getting the value of one cell at a time.

A couple of linked answers which also explain this point: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838900/google-apps-script-add-1-to-the-value-of-a-cell-in-a-spreadsheet-on-button-click/14838988#14838988) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937550/google-apps-script-function-that-gets-a-certain-colomn-in-spreadsheet/14937963#14937963)

Comment: If a whole range of cells is called and worked upon in a loop, as Phil is indicating can be done, then is it likely to require the loop to run backwards i.e. something like: for( var i = rangeValues.length-1; i > 0; i-- ) so that when you delete a row during that loop, it does not affect the length of the remaining loop-yet-to-be-covered; so the i variable in the loop can safely be used to correspond to the i in deleteRows(i) that we want to delete (otherwise the second and subsequent rows deleted will not be the expected ones)

Comment: Good point. As I was typing up this answer, I forgot that the goal was to delete rows. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Phil, Thanks so much for your help.. what a great way to be introduced to this forum.  I made the changes you recommended so now the line reads:  var value =  ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();    But now this is the error I'm getting: Cannot find method (class)getRange(number,number)          Once I figure out this part, I'll go back and try to use getValues to make my code more efficient.. thanks again for your help!

Comment: Looks like you'll need to make this change. `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` Note the difference here.

Comment: @Phil, thanks sooo much.. it works! But as you mentioned, it's quite slow.  I'm going to try to implement your solution using .getValues (where, if I understand correctly, I'll be pulling all the cell values into an array, then looping through the array and deleting rows with the same row number as the index of the array)... I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: As @David said, you should work backwards through the array so your indices line up. Example: if your rows are [1,2,3,4,5], then you go and delete the third item from this list. Then your list would be [1,2,4,5]. Suppose you then wanted to look at the 4th row. You would then be looking at "5". You would have skipped over 4. This issue can be solved by going backwards through the rows. (starting at i=values.length-1, and ending at i=0).

Comment: @Phil I really thought I had this... It runs without errors but it doesn't actually do anything.  Execution transcript says the last line executed is Range.getValues... Here's my code:               function EfficientDeleteClosedRows(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var end = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  var value = ss.getRange(3,1,end,1).getValues();
  
  for (var i = value.length-1; i = 0 ; i--) {
    
    if (value[i] === "Received" || value[i] === "Canceled") {
      
      ss.deleteRows(i + 3);
      
    };
  };
};

Comment: Change `i = 0` to `i >= 0`. The middle statement reads "While ** is true, continue executing the loop." So while `i` is greater than or equal to 0, keep executing the loop. If `i` is less than 0, don't execute the loop. Note: 0 is your stopping position. It is the first row of the spreadsheet. If you have a header row, you may want to stop when i=1, i.e. `i>=1`.